# magento get was and special price

Tags: php, magento, zend-framework

I have an easy one. I need to get the *was* and *special price* for a grouped product in `list.phtml`

I can get *was* and *special* for associated products but not the grouped product.

```
echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true);
```

It is not giving me the *was* and *special price*, only the *final price*.

However, it works on `view.phtml`

Any ideas?

Comment: too much code, break it down to the problem ...

Comment: did you look into *view.phtml*, to find out how it works ?

Comment: `$this` is a different context depending on the block. Look at the _block type_ for clues.